# Delay starting of an consumer as it depends upon a MaterializedView which is not in running state as yet

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a use case in which inside a consumer, I use a materializedview to execute some businesslogic (as shown in the code below). On restart of the spring boot application materializedview gets recreated from kafka topic, depending upon messages on the topic it can take small dealy to come into running state. If during this delay an message arrives on the other consumer which has the dependency on this MV to execute its logic then it fails.

**Consumer 1**

```
@Bean
public Consumer<KStream<String, Pojo> read() {      
     return messages-> messages
            .toTable(Materialized.<String, Pojo, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(STORE_NAME)
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(CustomSerdes.PojoSerde()));
}
```

**Consumer 2**

```
public class CustomProcessor implements Processor<String, Pojo> {

    private final InteractiveQueryService queryService;
    private ProcessorContext context;

    @Override
    public void close() {}

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, Pojo value) {
        queryService.getQueryableStore(STORE_NAME, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore())
        .all()
        .stream()
        .....
        business logic here 
        ....
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how to tackle such issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka Streams processors will not start completely and ready for processing unless the state stores are fully restored (for the processors under the same `applicaiton.id`). I assume that these two consumers are part of two distinct Kafka Streams processors, i.e. they each have their own separate `application.id`. You can introduce the following properties to control retrying `queryService.getQueryableStore(...)`.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.stateStoreRetry.maxAttempts 
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.stateStoreRetry.backOffInterval
```

The defaults are `1` and `1000` (milliseconds) respectively.

You can set some reasonable values depending on the time it takes to restore the state store to retry the processing.

This [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_interactive_queries) of the ref docs has more details on this.

If you want to build your own [retrying mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_retrying_critical_business_logic), that is also fine, but that may be more cumbersome. The above approach is far more concise and reasonable for interactive query API's.

Comment: You are correct Sobychacko both the cosumers are configured to start with different applicaiton.id. I will give these settings a try and revert. Thanks

Comment: The setting are bit different (according to context help)
```spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.state-store-retry.max-attempts=10
  spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.state-store-retry.backoff-period=1000```

However they have no effect as I keep getting the same exception:
Exception in thread "ReadPassagesApplication-7af11b20-b252-4566-b721-a03dcd69f06a-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: Cannot get state store my-store because the stream thread is STARTING, not RUNNING

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sobychacko, finally I got everything to work. Here is the complete solution for others (incase they hit the same issue)

**Application.properties**

```
#statestore retry configuration
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.state-store-retry.max-attempts=5
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.state-store-retry.backoff-period=1000
```

**Consumer listening to an topic for passage events**

```
@Bean
public Consumer<KStream<String, Pojo>> passages(@Lazy @Qualifier("passages-in-0-RetryTemplate") RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {
        return passages-> passages.process(() -> new PassagesEvaluator(retryTemplate));
    }
```

**PassageEvaluator class, has dependency on InteractiveQueryService for processing passages events, the code is placed in retryTemplate.execute(...) retryTemplate is configured from application properties**

```
public class PassagesEvaluator implements Processor<String, Pojo> {

    private final InteractiveQueryService queryService;
    private final RetryTemplate retryTemplate;
    private ProcessorContext context;

    @Override
    public void close() {}

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, Pojo value) {
        retryTemplate.execute(ctx -> {
              queryService.getQueryableStore(STORE_NAME, 
               QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore())
              .all()
              .stream()
               .....
                business logic here 
               ....        
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: Why did you need to wrap your logic within the `retryTemplate`? That's what the binder does if those properties are set. Wonder if there is some bug.

Comment: I couldn't get it working only with the properties that you suggested. Had to do it via [Retry mechanism][https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_retrying_critical_business_logic] that you suggested.